# apache Zeppelin is unable to show data from MongoDB But insert Query is working Fine

Tags: mongodb, apache-zeppelin

[image: strong text]

Apache Zeppelin is unable to show data from MongoDB But insert Query is working Fine.
I'm Following this Steps to make MongoDB Interpreter Here is the link-- https://github.com/bbonnin/zeppelin-mongodb-interpreter

Please help me out to show the data on Zeppelin NoteBook.

Answer (score 2):

`db.tablename.find({}).table()` to query in notebook: it will work

```
%Smart_mongodb
db.user.find({}).table()
```